# In VB.Net using an anonymous object type to create a generic class object

Tags: vb.net, generics, anonymous-types

I have a function that accepts a parameter of type object which is an anonymous type generated elsewhere.  I also have a generic class which I am trying to create an instance of using that anonymous type as the type passed to the generic class.  But I am unable to get this to work.

So here is basically what I have for my generic class:

```
Class Foo(Of T)
  ...
End Class
```

So in my function I have something like this:

```
Public Sub MyFunction(data As Object)
  'data is an anonymous Type

  dim item = new Foo(Of ??)
End Sub
```

I can't figure out what to give to the new Foo line to get this to work.  One thing I tried was to create a constructor on Foo which accepts a parameter of type T, so that the type is inferred from that, but that gives me this compile error when I call the constructor:

Too few type arguments to 'Foo(Of T)'

How do I get this to work so that the generic class accepts the anonymous type?

Comment: System.Object is not generic.  So you'll have very little use for a generic class.  Consider reflection.

Comment: I'm not seeing how Reflection would be of much help since my generic class needs the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `MyFunction` `data` from `object` to `T`.

```
Public Sub MyFunction(Of T)(data As T)
    Dim item = New Foo(Of T)()
End Sub
```

Comment: What about `data` object passed to the generic function? Where is it used?